# run android sdk from other drive in linux

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

I have installed Linux mint 17.2 on /dev/sda3 and my android sdk is on /dev/sda5

When I change permissions via terminal or GUI for android to executable, it revert back.

How can I run android or other applications from other partitions then root ?

Comment: what do you mean revert back? What's relevent here is not the physical device but their mount points

Comment: permission revert back, in GUI when I press allow executable file as program check to yes , it un-check automatically.

Is there any hack / user managemet to execute programs from other partition?

Comment: Like I said physical partitions are irrelevent what matters is how and where you have mounted them. It's extremely unusual for permissions to change on their own. Are you using a weird file system like FAT? Anyway this question really belongs on askubuntu and not here.

Comment: yes it is NTFS, thanks let me try in askubuntu :)

Comment: well there you are. NTFS isn't compatible with linux permissions, in fact it's a bad idea to use it at all on linux. The only time you should do so is when you want to share data between linux and windows on a dual boot, but nowadays who needs dual boot anyway thanks to virtualization.

Comment: Yes, thanks, changing file system worked.. Regards